# Storing a DB password in android keystore/ios keychain - xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, keychain, android-keystore, sqlcipher

I am trying to store an encrypted sqlcipher database password in the keystore/keychain.

I found this link -
http://www.howtobuildsoftware.com/index.php/how-do/ZPR/c-android-xamarin-monodroid-sqlcipher-correct-way-to-store-encryption-key-for-sqlcipher-database

but when i call it using -

```
 DependencyService.Get<IAuth>().CreateStore();
```

it gives me a null error.

Am I doing it correctly or where am I going wrong?

Should I be trying to store the sqlcipher database password in the keystore/keychain?

Answer (score 1):

If the `DependencyService.Get<>` is returning a `null`, make sure that you have assigned the `DependencyAttribute` within each of your implementations.

In the case of the `IAuth` implementation , you would add the following line in each of your iOS and Android assemblies where you have implemented the platform code:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(IAuthImplementation))]
```

Comment: thanks, this helped. Do you know if I should be trying to store the sqlcipher database password in the keystore/keychain? or where would I store it?

Comment: @Ciaran Storing the db password in the keystore|chain is perfectly fine, it is WAY better then clear text or some app encrypted file that you have to store the pwd in code to open, etc... The major question I would have is where is the password originating from? i.e. Is it server created and delivered to the client app via HTTPS/SSL?, is it unique per user?, etc...